# Angularjs route to different layout page using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing SPA in angularjs. I have two layout pages. There is one tab in the first layoutpage(Index.html) called Financial. Whenever i click on that page i want to redirect to another layout page. 
Below is my index.html

```
  //All js,css,angular files.
                <li><a ui-sref="FAQ">FAQ's</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="Careers">Careers</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Offers & Deals</a> </li>
                <li><a ui-sref="Financial ">Financial Reports</a> </li>
                <div class="container">
                <div ui-view></div>
                </div>
```

whenever i click on Financial Reports I want to redirect to new layout page and do not want to load any html in above ui-view. Below is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/m57BI5pivGzXD9UtwVtm?p=preview. May I know how can i handle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by new layout page ?

Comment: New page(Master page).... Current menus i do not want to display when i redirect. Currently i have FAQ,Careers etc but when i redirect i want redirect to another master page.

Comment: but what is that master page is that a page inside application or external application in whole?

Comment: that is page inside application only.

Comment: not quite sure if you want dynamic views based on links can see named views here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: I did not get any resources in google. In simple words window.location.href will redirect to new page. Same way whenever i click on financial tab i want to redirect to another master page.

Comment: I found one link. http://embed.plnkr.co/9Csur2/  My requirement is whenever i click on dashboard i want new state but i do not want menus Dashboard 
verify without params 
verify with email 
verify with code 
verify with email & code  in new page. Let me know if you did not understand Vinod.

Comment: I think you need to have a normal link for that not state like: `a< href="master2" >` because every state you have would be injected into  `ui-view`- so the menu would remain

Comment: Thanks s T x. Yes that will work but my application will not be single page application right? Lets say i will create master2.html. I can make master2.html  as SPA right? Please correct me. In master2.html i can use uiroute?

Comment: Don't think you can(not very good at Angular1 - only programmed 3 apps). However for what you want to achieve you can do 2 things:
1. include your menu inside every page you want to have it and not in `index.html' and have a default state(one of your menu links)'
2. use CSS with absolute positioning and bigger z-index then the basepage for that specific page you don't want to have the menu(simply put: show it over the page with menu(like a pop-up or a dialog))

Comment: Thanks. Yes i understood. I need to include menus in each page that will be injected in ui-view? Is this is the right way?

Comment: Is there any way i keep all menus in one page and can i able to inject it to ui-view?

Comment: Correct. I think you can load a template into view(if you use jQuery), I guess it would be an angular way if doing this too but you also can have a service that would return a string with a html structure of the menu and then append it to a `<nav></nav>` tag that would be present in every ui-template(that it's done by the help of jQuery too - the append())

Comment: Thanks. I just started working in Angular. May i get some website link to achive that?

Comment: or into that service you can to the same thing but with javascript with [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [ui-router-wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views), ui-router lets you add named views which helps you specify which view to use for whichever route you need . 
   So if you need to have a landing page with state `landing` you could specify something like ,

```
 .state('landing', {
                    url: "/",
                    data: { pageTitle: 'Landing Page' },
                    views: {
                        'landing': {
                            templateUrl: "<template-url>",
                            controller: "LandingController",
                            controllerAs: "landing"
                                   }
                           }
                   });
```

Which lets you specify the ui-view in your `index.html` like

```
<div ui-view="landing"></div>
```

And so if you need to have a particular url to use a different ui-view you could specify in the `views` object of the state .

```
 .state('alternateView', {
                    url: "/",
                    data: { pageTitle: 'Alternate page' },
                    views: {
                        'alternateUiViewTemplate': {
                            templateUrl: "<template-url>",
                            controller: "Alternate Controller",
                            controllerAs: "alternate"
                                   }
                           }
                   });
```

which lets you add to the index.html and have an extra ui-view holder,

```
<div ui-view="landing"></div>
<div ui-view="alternateUiViewTemplate"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. In ui-view="landing" i should load index.html and ui-view="alternateUiViewTemplate" i should be able to load some other pages. Ami right?

Comment: @sTx Sorry , dint get you .

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole No , `ui-view="landing"` `ui-view="alternateUiViewTemplate"` are placeholders for your required templates for each . You can use it according to your requirement and way . I would keep both ui-views in body inside index.html and use each for different templates required .

Comment: sorry it would resolve(after I read the link) - the OP main problem was that he need a way to link to a page where the navbar wouldn't exist but because now navbar is on the same level with ui-view it will always exist

Comment: He could keep the navbar inside `landing.html` and on any clicks on links in navbar use the other `alternateUiViewTemplate` ui-view for the other states .

Comment: @32teets i am trying to understand. thanks for your help. I am new to angularjs so i am struggling. may i get some related links on this?

Comment: So how can he hide the `landing` navbar when a specific link is navigated to?

Comment: Let;s say the navabar is like this: `Home|Pag1|Pag2` and if the user click `Home or Pag1` it goes to certain states and the navbar remain on top of them but if the he click `Pag2` it goes to a state with a certain content but the navbar shouldn't exist there

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki would help you I guess . There is a newer version of ui-router too if you want to try .

Comment: So , when he navigates to any other state the landing state would be removed if I am right , which would hide it .

Comment: Yep but he need it to be removed just for a specific state not for every one

Comment: So , he can have substates for `landing` like `landing.<state-name>` so all those states will use the same template which requires him to mention a nested `ui-view` inside `landing.html`  , and for states that does not require the navbar he would be specifying other states as mentioned previously .

Comment: :) This is more clear - i got it now(I've never looked to `loading` as a master page and just as a `nav` template)

Comment: Glad that you did @sTx . The benefits of ui-router comes with using nested states and named views.